# How can i attain responisveness for ios apps

Tags: ios, swift, iphone, ipad

I am working on an application in ios swift.
This is how it looks in iphones.[image]

and this is how it looks in ipads
[image]

I have used tableview to make this app. How can i fix it to look good on ipad too.

Comment: Autolayout and appropriate constraints based on size classes

Comment: can u point me to a resource where i can learn about size classes

Comment: https://www.raywenderlich.com/1343912-adaptive-layout-tutorial-in-ios-12-getting-started

Comment: ok thankyou paul its very informative and detailed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
There are many ways to do it, one of those is you can use auto layouts and differentiate between iPad and iPhone using size classes.

Add a variation in size inspector if you are using storyboards. For iPhones its Compact width and Regular height and for iPads its Regular width and Regular heights.You can visit this link https://www.bignerdranch.com/blog/designing-for-size-classes-in-ios/ for more details.

If you are doing through code then you can differentiate between iPhone and iPadusing below code snippet

      if UIDevice().userInterfaceIdiom == .phone {
          //This is iPhone
          //Here Provide your content size for iPhone
                                       } 
      else { 
          //This is iPad
          //Here Provide your content size for iPad
           }
```

Answer (score 1):

You want to use a stackview.  Basically group your widgets horizontally or vertically inside stackviews.  The stack views can be nested.  You should not use any constraints except on your scrollview itself.

There was a wonderful WWDC video, I think from 2018, that of course I can't find right now.  But AUTOLAYOUT and STACKVIEW are the keywords for which you want to search.

[Here](https://developer.apple.com/videos/play/wwdc2017/412/) is one but it isn't the one I'm actually looking for.  It should get you started though.

Answer (score 1):

The *"direct"* iPhone app *"translations"* for iPad very rarely look perfect. You might want to think about redesigning your UI to use the available screen space better. The size classes and proper autolayout will definitely make your app look better but will never make the app look like it was tailored for the iPad.

You might want to think about redesigning your UI not to only re-size properly but also provide more usability on devices with larger screens. A couple of UI components that can help you do that are **UICollectionView** (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview, https://www.raywenderlich.com/9334-uicollectionview-tutorial-getting-started),
and **UISplitViewController** (https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uisplitviewcontroller, https://www.raywenderlich.com/265-uisplitviewcontroller-tutorial-getting-started).